# how check if the data is complete load to use async pipe Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, httpclient

I have a json file to simulate a request to an API I am using httpClient in my service I return it

service

[image]

this is my home component

[image]

this is my html home component

[image]

but I am doing something wrong because I can print the data but, one of the element is render empty
this is the result I have

[image]

How I can prevent this I am new on this thanks so much in advance.

Comment: What data is coming back in your json response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your home component template; it looks like you are rendering a component called `app-card` just before your `*ngFor` loop.

Could that be the empty card.

```html
<div class="col-md-4>
  <app-card></app-card>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how to do it?

Comment: Theres a how-to guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers